# 'Compile error: Method or data member not found' on ListBox when Workbook opens

Tags: vba, listbox

I get that compile error only when the I open the workbook. I don't get what is triggering the 'click' event just by opening a workbook.
Once the workbook is open and I get rid of the message error, the code works.

These are cascading Activex listboxes on a worksheet. The error is related to line "Me.ListBox2.List = Findstring"

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

On Error Resume Next

Me.ListBox2.List = FindString(Me.ListBox1.Value, "TipoDeProdutos", "Material")

Me.ListBox3.Clear
Me.ListBox3.ListFillRange = ""

End Sub
```

FindString is a UDF that returns a Variant.

Comment: What version of excel are you working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once had the same problem. I found that **if I changed the name from ListBox2 to something else eg ListBoxb the problem disappeared. If I imported the old name the problem returned**. I was working with excel2007. Try to change the name of ListBox1 and if don't works try the ListBox2.

Comment: This works in Excel 365, whatever the reason. Many thanks!